# TCP or UDP for lots of connections?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, p2p

I want to create a P2P network with the following characteristics:

- low latency is not really important
- loosing packages is okay
- the nodes would only send tiny amounts of data around
- there will be no NAT/firewall issues, every node has an open port on its public ip
- every node is connected to every other node

Usually I would use TCP for anything not time-critical but the last requirements causes the nodes to have lots of open connections for a long time. If I remember correctly, using TCP to connect to 1000 servers would mean I had to use 1000 ports to handle these connections. UDP on the other hand, would only require a single port for each node.

So my question is: Is TCP able to handle the above requirements in a network with e.g. 1000 nodes without tweaking the system? Would UDP be better suited in this case? Is there anything else that would be a deal-breaker for either protocol?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It's an architectural design question, and possibly a networking question. It *may* be on topic on Programmers or elsewhere, but as currently written it is not within the scope defined by our help center.

Comment: Recommend reviewing [TCP vs UDP](http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP) for a comparison. Compare that to your list of characteristics and make your choice. UDP would most likely be the most appropriate choice.

Answer (score 3):

With UDP you control the "connection state" and it is pretty much the best way to do anything peer to peer related *IF* you have a high number of nodes or care about  bandwidth, memory and CPU overhead. By moving all the control to your application in regards to the "connection state" of each node you minimize the amount of wasted resources by making it fit your needs exactly.

You will bypass a lot of operating system specific weirdness that limits the effectiveness of TCP with high numbers of connections. There is TIME_WAIT bloat and tens to hundreds of OS specific settings which will need tweaking for every user of your P2P app if it needs those high numbers. A test app I made which allowed you to use UDP with ack or TCP showed only a 10% difference in performance regardless of operating system using UDP. TCP performance was always lower than the best UDP and its performance varied wildly by over 600% depending upon the OS. With tweaks you can make most OS perform roughly the same using TCP but by default most are not properly tweaked.

So in my opinion it is harder to make a reliable UDP P2P network compared to TCP but it is often needed. However I would only advise that route it if you were quite experienced with networking as there are a lot of "gotchas" to deal with. There are libraries which help with this like Raknet or Enet. They provide ways to do reliable UDP but it still takes a higher amount of networking knowledge to know how this all ties in together, whereas with TCP it is mostly hidden from you.

In a peer to peer network you often have messages like NODE PINGs that you may not care if each one is always received, you just care if you have received one recently. ie You may send a ping every 10 seconds, and disconnect the node after 60 seconds of no ping. This would mean you would need 6 ping packets in a row to fail, which is highly unlikely unless the node is really down. If you received even one ping in that 60 second period then the node is still active. A TCP implementation of this would have involved more latency and bandwidth as it makes sure EACH ping message gets through and will block any other data going out until it does. And since you cannot rely on TCP to reliably tell you if a connection is dead, you are forced to add similar PING features for TCP, on top of all the other things TCP is already doing extra with your packets.

Games also often have data that if its not received by a client it is no big deal because there are more packets coming in a few milliseconds which will invalidate any missed packets. ie Player is moving from A to Z over a time span of 1 second, his client sends out each packet, roughly 40 milliseconds apart ABCDEFG__I__KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ Do we really care if we miss "H and J" since every 40ms we are receiving updates? Not really, this is where prediction can come into it, but this is usually not relevant to most P2P projects. If that was TCP instead of UDP then it would have increased bandwidth requirements and added latency to the rest of the packets being received as the data will be resent until it arrives, on top of the extra latency it is already adding by acking everything.

Essentially you can lower latency and network overhead for many messages in a peer to peer network using UDP. However there will always be some messages which *NEED* to be sent reliably and that requires you to basically implement some reliable way to get packets to that node, similar to that of TCP. And this is where you need some level of expertise if you want a reliable peer to peer network. Some things to look into include sequencing packets with a number, message ACKs, etc.

If you care a lot about efficiency or really need tens of thousands of connections then implementing your specific protocol in UDP will always be better than TCP. But there are cases to be made for TCP, like if the time to make the project matters or if you are a new to network programming.

Answer (score 2):

> If I remember correctly, using TCP to connect to 1000 servers would mean I had to use 1000 ports to handle these connections.

You remember wrong.
Take a web server which is listening on port 80 and can handle 1000s of connections at the same time on this single port. This is because a connection is defined by the tuple of `{client-ip,client-port,server-ip,server-port}`. And while server-ip and server-port are the same for all connections to this server the client-ip and client-port are not. Even if the client-ip is the same (i.e. same client) the client would pick a different source port.

> ... with e.g. 1000 nodes without tweaking the system?

This depends on the system since each of the open connections needs to preserve the state and thus needs memory. This might be a problem for embedded systems with only little memory.

In any case: if your protocol is just sending small messages and if packet loss, reordering or duplication are acceptable than UDP might be the better choice because the overhead (connection setup, ACK..) is smaller and it takes less memory. You could also use a single socket to exchange data with all 1000 nodes whereas with TCP you would need a separate socket for each connection (socket is not the same as port!). Using only a single socket might allow for a simpler application design.

Comment: It is still possible for "port exhaustion" to occur with TCP. If you have a single listening socket then you are theoretically limited to 65535 per remote IP. And it is usually much less than that, Windows had settings in the past limiting it to ~5000. Combined with poor TIME_WAIT handling on the OS part you can easily find yourself port exhausted on particular remote IPs. I have seen this on high throughput front ends that go to a single backend. However this should not be a problem for a P2P app like that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I want to amend the answer by Steffen with a few points:

1. 1000 connections are nothing for any normal computer and OS.
2. UDP fits your requirements. It might be easier to program because it is message oriented. TCP provides a stream of bytes. You need to layer a messaging protocol on top of that which is not that easy. Also, you need to handle broken TCP connections by reconnecting.
3. Ports are not scarce. No problem with consuming 1000 ports.